# How to make a generic getter like z.infer<> in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, getter, zod

I've been learning Typescript for a few months and i started to discover zod recently, and i wonder how to build such a util getter such as `z.infer<>`, `z.input<>` or even `z.output<>`

What i understand is that `z` is a class that has a getter "method" that takes a generic and it returns a type, but i have no idea of how this works

I tried to replicate it but couldn't figure it out, can someone help?

Comment: I had to do this for my [project](https://github.com/kelsny/synth), and essentially, the classes already hold the type you want - the getter type is just to make it easier to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

If we have some class that has a generic type and uses it:

```
class Validator<T> { validate(value: any): value is T { /* implementation does not matter */ return true; } }
```

Then we can extract that generic type with `infer`:

```
type Infer<V> = V extends Validator<infer T> ? T : never;
```

You'll be able to use it like this:

```
const validator = new Validator<string>();

type S = Infer<typeof validator>; // string
```

This is the basis of Zod's `z.Infer`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZXAew)

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this requires a specific approach; it's not a straightforward task but rather a clever trick. Follow these steps:

1. Create a module named `some.ts`:

```js
export const javascript = "I am a value."
export type output<T> = T
```

2. In your main working file: `index.ts`:

```js
import * as some from "./some.ts"

console.log(some.javascript)
type output = some.output<"It works!">
```

- Now, you are free to use the `some` variable just like `z`.

Answer (score 0):

From my quick digging of the source code, these types seem to be defined in [`helpers/types.ts`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/deno/lib/types.ts#L50):

```
export type TypeOf<T extends ZodType<any, any, any>> = T["_output"];
export type input<T extends ZodType<any, any, any>> = T["_input"];
export type output<T extends ZodType<any, any, any>> = T["_output"];
export type { TypeOf as infer };
// ...
export abstract class ZodType<
  Output = any,
  Def extends ZodTypeDef = ZodTypeDef,
  Input = Output
> {
  readonly _type!: Output;
  readonly _output!: Output;
  readonly _input!: Input;
  readonly _def!: Def;
// ...
```

That's how you can build them.